# If $ u,v $ are solutions of reaction -diffusion equation does $ u^v $ also a solution with $u=v'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $u$ and $v$ two solutions of diffusion-reaction equation  $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \kappa\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + u - u^3\tag{E}$$ under some initial boundary conditions  such that $u,v $ are of class infinity with $u=v'$ ,Does this imply that  $ u^v $ also a solution of the equation $(E)$ ?

Comment: What exactly is $v'$, it can not be a simple derivative. // Is $u^v$ a typo for some original $u''$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, yes I meant simple derivative

Comment: But what does that mean for a function $v(x,t)$ of two variables?

Comment: But I claimed that  solutions should be in some specified boundary condition for example at t=0